# How to reverse engineer structs in radare2?

Tags: radare2, c, struct

Is there any way to indentify structs in radare2?

when i tried to look them, they look like normal variables, i seen people using td and tl command but I don't know how to use them. If you know please explain...

Comment: it is possible that structure recovery might not be implemented yet. Did you check using debug info?

Comment: how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

According to the official [radare2 book](https://book.rada.re/analysis/types.html?highlight=td#structure-immediates), you have to reverse the struct manually by understanding the features of the program. Then you can overwrite the variable by struct names such as for instance:

If you have this code:

```
mov rax, qword [rsi + 8]
```

You can do:

```
"td struct ms1 { uint64_t a; int member1; };"
aht ms1.member1
```

Then the code will be documented:

```
[0x000052f0]> pd 1
0x000052f0      488b4608       mov rax, qword [rsi + ms1.member1]
```

There is nothing automatic in this process.